# Child meta sites mistakenly suggest user to acquire a badge which isn't avalable on that site

Tags: bug, badges, per-site-meta

Check the following screenshot from CS meta:

[image]

It says,

> Take the tour and earn your first badge

Clicking the button redirects to the tour page of the main site and scrolling it doesn't change anything in the meta. Which is obvious as the badge `informed` doesn't exist on meta, unlike the main SE sites. However, this phenomenon is true for other sites as well. Is it a developer oversight?

Comment: The question seems to old. Because now the site gives you the `Informed` badge.

Comment: No, it's giving the badge currently. I checked it.

Comment: Meta sites always remain a bit weird as it uses the same engine as on main. On meta you can also acquire reputation but only your reputation on main is shown. You can still earn the reputation related badges on Meta based on your 'meta" reputation. All in all not an oversight, [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: You [earned the Informed badge](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/informed?userid=92505) last year on the main site, even if you use the  (?)->Tour on any site's Meta you still are only awarded the badge one time on the main site.

Comment: I think the `Take the tour and earn your first badge` button should be removed from all child meta sites